# Compare values of <Key, Value> Pairs and sort them

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, compare, keyvaluepair

I have Pairs that I would like to sort. I have already done the compare implementation and it seems to be working.

I also saw a solution online but the problem is that it doesn't allow it to be static.

```
public static ArrayList <Pair<Integer, Integer>> pairList = new ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>>();    

public static Pair<Integer, Integer> pair1 = new Pair<>(6, 7);
public static Pair<Integer, Integer> pair2 = new Pair<>(7, 7)
```

**This is where I'm getting the Error `Change compare() to static` with the solution that I'm testing out.**

**Method that I'm testing out:**

```
public  class MachineNoComparator implements Comparator <Pair<Integer, Integer>> {
    public int compare(Pair<Integer, Integer> o1, Pair<Integer, Integer> o2) {
        return o1.getMachineNo().compareTo(o2.getMachineNo());
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you don't really understand what the static keyword does. That should be your first step.

Comment: Some code seems to be missing. Where do you get "the error"?

Comment: @Gana, I am not sure I have understood the issue: you mean it won't work if I change the compare method to make it static?

Comment: can we not use CAPS?

Comment: No worries guys I have fixed it. The problem was solved by removing implements Comparator from the class.

Answer (score -1):

You probably call compare as

```
compare(pair1,pair2);
```

pair1 and pair2 are static and compare not. When you pass static fields to a function, the function also has to be static. This is the reason of why you take this error.

You can solve this by changing compare method to;

```
public static int compare(Pair<Integer, Integer> o1, Pair<Integer, Integer> o2) {
    return o1.getMachineNo().compareTo(o2.getMachineNo());
}
```

or fields to;

```
public Pair<Integer, Integer> pair1 = new Pair<>(6, 7);
public Pair<Integer, Integer> pair2 = new Pair<>(7, 7);
```

But you should have a look what 'static' keyword is and what it does.